# How to change marker color?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have defined a marker named `marker1` with some options as follows:

```
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: cPoint,
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 4,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 1.0,
        fillColor:'green',
        fillOpacity: 0.6
        }
    });
```

Later I want to change the color of the marker. I am using the following line. But I get an error. Can someone guide me?

```
marker1.setOptions({ icon: { fillColor: 'red' }});
```

What is the correct syntax for the above line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
iconOptions = marker1.getIcon();
iconOptions.fillColor = 'red';
marker1.setIcon(iconOptions);
```

The Symbol class doesn't seem to have any methods on it itself, otherwise I'd have assumed you could do setColor or setProperty, something like that.

Alternatively you could re-set the entire symbol:

```
iconOptions = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 4,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWeight: 1.0,
    fillColor:'red',
    fillOpacity: 0.6
}
marker1.setIcon(iconOptions);
```